# How can I #include a file with encrypted string?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, encryption, mingw

I am writing a C app on Windows with MinGW/gcc. I need to use the #include directive to include a file that contains an encrypted string. The string will be decrypted at runtime. I want to do this so the string will not be visible if looking at the executable with a hex editor.

I tried this, but it doesn't work. You get the idea, though:

```
char *hidden_str =
#include "encrypted_text.dat"
```

There may be unescaped stuff in there that's confusing the compiler. I don't know. I don't know what happens to it after it's encrypted.

If there's a better approach to this, I'm open to it.

Comment: Did you try adding it as a resource ?

Comment: Can you open the file as a file at runtime and read it in?

Comment: You would not use the preprocessor include directive in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed and configured MSYS when you installed MinGW, you should have access to a command called [`xxd`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/xxd.1.php), which takes a hex dump of a file. By using the `-i` command line flag, you can get it to output a C-friendly file which you can easily import.

An example call would be:

```
xxd -i in_file output.h
```

The contents of `output.h` would then look like:

```
unsigned char in_file[] = {
  0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f
};
unsigned int in_file_len = 5;
```

You can then include that file into your C source code and have access to it:

```
#include "output.h"

unsigned int i;
for(i = 0; i < in_file_len; i++)
{
    printf("%c", in_file[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't like binary data in the file.

Try doing this instead:

```
char hidden_str[] = {
    65, 66, 67, ...
};
```

It's not that difficult to write a simple program to generate the relevant lines of data from the .dat file, with a limited number of characters per line.

Comment: [xd](https://www.fourmilab.ch/xd/) and [xxd](http://man.cx/xxd) can generate those kinds of files.

Answer (score 1):

Encode it as hex/octal.  I'm not sure what the simplest way would be to encode it -- you could use, eg, "\xAB\xCF...", the same with octal, or you could use an array initializer something like (don't quote me on this):

```
char hidden_str[64] = {0xAB, 0xCf, ...};
```

(You could even use decimal values for the initializer.)

Obviously, whatever you do you'll have to pre-process the encrypted text into a hex representation -- an easy job for a "toy" program.