# Include static data/text file

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I have a text file (>50k lines) of ascii numbers, with string identifiers, that can be thought of as a collection of data vectors. Based on user input, the application only needs one of these data vectors at runtime.

As far as I can see, I have 3 options for getting the information from this text file:

1. Keep it as a text file, extract the required vector at run-time. I believe the downside is that you can't have a relative path in the code, so the user would have to point to the file's correct location (?). Or alternatively, get the configure script to inject the absolute path as a macro.
2. Convert it to a static unsigned char using [xxd](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/xxd.1.php) (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240362/758811)) and then include the resulting file. Downside is that a 5MB file turns into a 25MB include file. Am I correct in thinking that this 25MB is loaded into memory for the duration of the runtime?
3. Convert it to an object and link using [objcopy](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objcopy) as explained [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967). This seems to keep the file size about the same -- are there other trade-offs?

Is there a standard/recommended method for doing this? I can use C or C++ if that makes a difference.

Thanks.

(Running on linux with gcc)

Comment: Um why can't you have a relative path in the code? Filenames such as "../data/datafile.dat" are perfectly valid (assuming unix, other operating systems are similar).

Comment: Yup, Windows supports relative paths as well. (Finally something those Unix people can't feel smugly superior about!)

Comment: As far as I am aware, relative paths are relative to the directory where the program is executed from -- thus, if you change the directory from which you run, the relative path is no longer accurate.

Comment: Simpler solution, have an environment variable storing the file name or pass it as a argument to the binary (or both).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with number 1 and pass the filepath into the program as an argument. There's nothing wrong with doing that and it is simple and straight-forward.

Comment: Used the make file to get the compilation directory, and then a relative file path in the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the answers here:

[Directory of running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737996/directory-of-running-program-on-linux)

The top voted answer gives you a glue how to handle your data file. But instead of the home folder I would suggest to save it under [/usr/share](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#PURPOSE26) as explained in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'd preffer to use zlib (and both ways are possible:side file or include with compressed data).